# Reproducing the result from Map() with mapply()

Tags: r

Take the following data frame and vector,

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 4:6, z = 7:9)
v <- c(5, 10, 15)
```

Assume I want to multiply `df` columnwise by the elements of `v`, meaning `df[1] * v[1]`, `df[2] * v[2]`, and `df[3] * v[3]`

I can do this with `Map`

```
> Map(`*`, df, v)
$x
[1]  5 10 15

$y
[1] 40 50 60

$z
[1] 105 120 135
```

Now, since `Map` is defined as

```
> Map
function (f, ...) 
{
    f <- match.fun(f)
    mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
}
<bytecode: 0x3950e00>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

it seems logical that I should be able to reproduce the above exactly with the following call to `mapply`, but this is not the case.

```
> mapply(`*`, df, v, simplify = FALSE)
# Error in .Primitive("*")(dots[[1L]][[1L]], dots[[2L]][[1L]],   
#   simplify = dots[[3L]][[1L]]) : operator needs one or two arguments
```

The problem seems to be within the arguments of `"*"`, and those arguments are

```
> args("*")
function (e1, e2) 
NULL
```

So two more tries yield similar errors.

```
> mapply(`*`, e1 = df, e2 = v, simplify = FALSE)
# Error in .Primitive("*")(e1 = dots[[1L]][[1L]], e2 = dots[[2L]][[1L]],  : 
#   operator needs one or two arguments
> mapply(`*`, ..1 = df, ..2 = v, simplify = FALSE)
# Error in .Primitive("*")(..1 = dots[[1L]][[1L]], ..2 = dots[[2L]][[1L]],  : 
#   operator needs one or two arguments
```

What is the issue here? And how can I reproduce (exactly) the result from

```
Map(`*`, df, v)
```

with `mapply`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that `Map` calls

```
mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

**not**

```
mapply(FUN = f, ..., simplify = FALSE)
```

and of course R is case sensitive. Try

```
mapply(`*`, df, v, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
# $x
# [1]  5 10 15
# 
# $y
# [1] 40 50 60
# 
# $z
# [1] 105 120 135
```

instead. With `simplify = FALSE`, it's trying to call

```
`*`(df[[1]], v[1], simplify = FALSE)
```

which is what is giving that error.

Comment: THis is a pitfall with naming considering `sapply` is `simplify =`